# Using lstm in TensorFlow for prediction by time sequence, while my result can be so bad and absurd

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have some 20 GDPs in a group, and I wanted to use LSTM NN in TensorFlow to predict the next 10 years GDP performance.
As the original data shows, the GDPs are supposed to increase exponentially, but my result through the lstm suggest the totally opposite trend, I found it very very confused to debug!! Is there anything wrong with my network architecture?

I tried to adjust the learning rate from 0.1 to 0.0001, and have changed the batch_size, time_step, and the run_unit_size, both in range of (2, 20), but none of those method works.

```html
raw data: 
year      gdp
1996    349600
1997    422100
1998    479100
1999    389711
2000    428654
2001    486430
2002    565532
2003    677583
2004    950951
2005    1453209
2006    1831073
2007    2454598
2008    3018032
2009    4594015
2010    5736350
2011    7678600
2012    8793200
2013    10017593
2014    11153849
2015    11933430
2016    12933462
```

getting batches of training data:

```py
def get_train_data(normalized):
    target = list()
    label = list()
    for i in range(len(a_np) - time_step - 1):
        target.append(normalized[i:i + time_step])
        label.append(normalized[i + 1:i + time_step + 1])
    return target, label
```

the basic info of LSTM:

```
time_step = 4
rnn_unit = 20
batch_size = 5
input_size = 1
output_size = 1
lr = 0.008
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, time_step, input_size])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, time_step, output_size])
weights = {
        'in': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([input_size, rnn_unit])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([rnn_unit, 1]))
    }
biases = {
    'in': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[rnn_unit, ])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1, ]))
}
```

3 layers lstm from input-hidden through to lstm finally to the output-hidden layer:

```
def lstm(batch):
    w_in = weights['in']
    b_in = biases['in']
    input = tf.reshape(X, [-1, input_size])
    input_rnn = tf.matmul(input, w_in) + b_in
    input_rnn = tf.reshape(input_rnn, [-1, time_step, rnn_unit])
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_unit, forget_bias=0.2, state_is_tuple=True)
    init_state = cell.zero_state(batch, dtype=tf.float32)
    output_rnn, final_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, input_rnn, initial_state=init_state, dtype=tf.float32)
    output = tf.reshape(output_rnn, [-1, rnn_unit])
    w_out = weights['out']
    b_out = biases['out']
    pred = tf.matmul(output, w_out) + b_out
    return pred, final_states
```

loss function and optimizer:

```py
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.reshape(Y, [-1]) - tf.reshape(pred, [-1])))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)
```

```html
this is the predicted result
2017    [11262389.]
2018    [11572339.]
2019    [11730970.]
2020    [11825313.]
2021    [11873324.]
2022    [11906612.]
2023    [11924690.]
2024    [11935304.]
2025    [11941413.]
```

Comment: Hi, 
Is your issue resolved now. Else, I tried reproducing the error and I got the error, 
    "NameError: name 'pred' is not defined". Can you please share the complete code so that we can work towards its resolution. Thanks.